# JSON extract date from matching string

Tags: c#, c++, json

I am entirely new to JSON, and haven't got any familiarity with it at all. I'm tinkering around with some JSON data extracts to get a feel for it.

Currently, I have a chat export which has a large number of keys. Within these keys are a "date" key, and a "from_id" key.

I would like to search a JSON file for a matching value on the "from_id" key, and return all the values against the "date" keys with a matching "from_id" value.

For example:

```json
{
 "name": "FooBar Chat Group",
 "type": "textchat",
 "id": 123456789,
 "messages": [
  {
{
   "id": 252930,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-03-03T01:39:30",
   "date_unixtime": "1614735570",
   "from": "Person1",
   "from_id": "user1234",
   "text": "This is a message!"
  },
  {
   "id": 252931,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-03-03T01:41:03",
   "date_unixtime": "1614735663",
   "from": "Person2",
   "from_id": "user9876",
   "text": "This is a reply!"
  },
  {
   "id": 252932,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-03-03T01:42:01",
   "date_unixtime": "1614735721",
   "from": "Person2",
   "from_id": "user9876",
   "text": "This is some other text!"
  },
  {
   "id": 252933,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-03-03T01:42:44",
   "date_unixtime": "1614735764",
   "from": "Person1",
   "from_id": "user1234",
   "text": "Yeah, indeed it is!"
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to search from_id "user1234", and for it to return the following:

- 2021-03-03T01:39:30
- 2021-03-03T01:42:44

These are the two dates that have a matching from_id.

How would I go about doing something like this, please?

I am entirely new to this, so a super basic explanation with resources would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What language do you use and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Serge I'd like to do this in C#, but I'm open to trying it C++. I haven't tried anything so far, unfortunately, as it's my first ever introduction to JSON. I'd appreciate any recommendation for decent first-timer tutorials, too. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, but your json is not valid , you don't need to post the full json, but at least you have to post a valid  part starting from the root.

Comment: Just updated that, it should be correct now without revealing any personal info. Cheers.

Comment: Given that you're new to programming and unsure how to proceed, I highly recommend focusing on only one language until you develop solid programming skills, including the ability to research and translate techniques from one language to another without asking broad questions seeking a tutorial. If you're familiar with C# then stick with that. It's okay to make a firm decision instead of adopting the "any language is fine" mentality. That is also a much better fit for Q&A on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, and I'll certainly take this on board going forward. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this c# code. At first you have to parse your json strig to create an object from string. Then you can use LINQ to get the data you need

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JArray messages = (JArray) JObject.Parse(json)["messages"];

string from_id="user1234";

DateTime[] dates = messages
                .Where(m=> (string) m["from_id"] ==from_id)
                .Select(m => (DateTime) m["date"])
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: This worked amazingly. I was able to implement this into C# rather easily. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your sample is part of a JSON Array - starts with [ and ends with ] - you should be able to iterate and conditionally select what you want.

In javascript, you can use a `for of` to iterate through and an `if` to match your request:

```
for(let item of array){
  if(item['from_id'] == 'user1234')
    console.log(item.date);
}
```

As we don't know the language you're actually using, a more wide code version of it could be something like:

```
for(let i=0;i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i]['from_id'] == 'user1234'){
    print(array[i]['date']);
  }
}
```